# http and IO errors using uploadify, S3, Paperclip, Rails 3

Tags: http, io, uploadify

I am keep getting these two errors randomly, in IO error case the file gets upload but in Http error case it does not. But why I am getting these errors?

Answer (score 0):

Well I forgot to mention that I am using Heroku as well. :) SO in my case there where couple of reasons for the error.

- Request timeout error due to by default timeout value at heroku which was 15, increased to 45 and somehow it starts working for atleast 35 seconds requests. But Heroku has its issues with these timeouts so please read those at heroku site.
- There was an issue with rendering, I replaced the redirect call with render and it worked fine. (Helpful when you are not sure if there is any bugy code inside your view.)